# scroll is not enabled in textareafield with ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

textareafield scroll is not enabled with android device?

it work fine with browser but when I tested in device, scroll is not supported in both ios and android.

my syntax is :

```
var panel=new Ext.Panel({
    height:200,
    scrollable:true,
    items:[{
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        name: 'sendbox',
        maxRows: 4,
        itemId: 'messagesendboxid'
    }]
});
```

anyone have any alternate way for textaareafield? plz help i had wasted so much time on this topic, so plz help if anyone know solution about this problem.

Comment: I am too facing the same problem. The textareafield is not scrollable if there are 10 lines to show. It truncates the content after 5th line. Vertical scroll bar is not shown only in devices. Works fine in browser. A bug TOUCH-1941 has been reproted which still not fixed in 2.3.1 sencha touch. Related workaround link is at  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180207-TextArea-scroll-on-iOS-not-working&p=943600&viewfull=1#post943600